# Spawning ball when client connects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to spawn a bouncing ball that both client and server can see.
The ball has to be spawned when the client connects and the next scene (where the ball is bouncing) is loaded.

The problem is that the method OnPlayerConnected() does not get called, does anyone know any alternatives and why it doesn't work?

```
public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour {

public string connectionIP = "127.0.0.1";
public int connectionPort = 25001;
bool isClientConnected = false;

void Awake()
{
    // Make sure list is empty and request a new list
    MasterServer.RequestHostList("MyUniqueGameType");
}



// Use this for initialization
void OnGUI()
{
    HostData[] data = MasterServer.PollHostList ();
    // Go through all the hosts in the host list
    foreach (var element in data) 
    {
        //Debug.Log ("server found");
        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal ();    
        var name = element.gameName + " " + element.connectedPlayers + " / " + element.playerLimit;
        GUILayout.Label (name);  
        GUILayout.Space (5);
        string hostInfo;
        hostInfo = "[";
        foreach (var host in element.ip)
            hostInfo = hostInfo + host + ":" + element.port + " ";
        hostInfo = hostInfo + "]";
        GUILayout.Label (hostInfo);  
        GUILayout.Space (5);
        GUILayout.Label (element.comment);
        GUILayout.Space (5);
        GUILayout.FlexibleSpace ();
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (10, 30, 120, 20), "Client Connect")) 
        {
            Network.Connect (connectionIP, connectionPort);
            isClientConnected = true;
            Application.LoadLevel ("scene1");

            //  Debug.Log ("spawning ball");
            //  SpawnBall();


        }
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal ();  

    }


    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (10, 50, 120, 20), "Initialize Server"))
    {
        Network.InitializeServer (2, connectionPort, !Network.HavePublicAddress ());
        //  Network.InitializeServer (2, 25002, !Network.HavePublicAddress ());
        MasterServer.RegisterHost ("MyUniqueGameType", "JohnDoes game", "l33t game for all");
                    /*
                    while(!isClientConnected)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("waiting for client");
                    }   
                    */

        Application.LoadLevel("scene1");

    }
}

void OnPlayerConnected(NetworkPlayer player)
{
    Debug.Log ("OnPlayerConnected");
    SpawnBall();
}


void SpawnBall()
{
    GameObject objPrefab = Resources.Load("Ball") as GameObject;
    GameObject obj = Instantiate(objPrefab) as GameObject;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load the new scene, this script stops executing. So the message handler `OnPlayerConnected` will never be called on either client or server.

What you could do instead is use an RPC (Remote Procedure Call) to have the client notify the server when it has connected and loaded the scene (this would go in the second scene):

```
void Start() {
    if(Network.isClient) {
        networkView.RPC("SpawnBall", RPCMode.AllBuffered)
    }
}

[RPC]
void SpawnBall(NetworkViewID viewID, Vector3 location) {
    GameObject objPrefab = Resources.Load("Ball") as GameObject;
    GameObject obj = Instantiate(objPrefab) as GameObject;
}
```

Now when the client loads the scene, he will send an RPC to the server telling him to spawn a ball. Note in the `Start` function I use `Network.isClient` to specify that this code should only be executed when a client loads the scene. `RPCMode.AllBuffered` will send the RPC to all connected players, including the client that sent it.

RPCs are a valuable tool and you should become familiar with them if doing networking in Unity.

Comment: Thanks alot man! it works without RPC only on the client but when now I use RPC i now get the error: 

Can't send RPC function since no connection was started.
UnityEngine.NetworkView:RPC(String, RPCMode, Object[])
SpawnBall:Start() (at Assets/scripts/SpawnBall.cs:11)

Both players can move and can see eachother moving so there's nothing wrong with the connection i guess..

Comment: nevermind, i've placed loadlevel into the method onconnectedtoserver, it works now